# How do I configure Betamax to use SSL for my Spock tests?

Tags: testing, groovy, spock, betamax

I have been trying to configure Betamax v2.0.0-alpha-1 to mock HTTP(S) calls from my spock tests. Calls to non-SSL sites work but a call to an HTTPS site causes the following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've boiled the code down to that shown below and calling `groovy BetamaxTestSpec.groovy` should give you the exception. As you can see in the code, I'm using the jersey-client library.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/dedickinson/6ad96679a15b24b2e3d3

Code:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('software.betamax:betamax-junit:2.0.0-alpha-1')
@Grab('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1')
import org.junit.Rule
import software.betamax.ProxyConfiguration
import software.betamax.TapeMode
import software.betamax.junit.Betamax
import software.betamax.junit.RecorderRule
import spock.lang.Specification

import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class BetamaxTestSpec extends Specification {
    @Rule
    RecorderRule recorderRule = new RecorderRule(ProxyConfiguration.builder()
            .sslEnabled(true)
            .build())

    @Betamax(tape = 'jCenterKeywordQuery.tape', mode = TapeMode.WRITE_ONLY)
    def "Test basic keyword query with JCenter"() {
        given:
        def searcher = new Searcher()
        def result = searcher.searchJCenter('groovy*')
        expect:
        1 == 1
    }

    @Betamax(tape = 'mvnKeywordQuery.tape', mode = TapeMode.WRITE_ONLY)
    def "Test basic keyword query with Maven Central"() {
        given:
        def searcher = new Searcher()
        def result = searcher.searchMavenCentral('groovy')
        expect:
        1 == 1
    }

    class Searcher {
        def searchJCenter(qry) {
            new JsonSlurper().parseText ClientBuilder.newClient().
                    target('https://api.bintray.com/search/packages/maven/'.toURI()).
                    queryParam('q', qry).
                    request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(String)
        }

        def searchMavenCentral(qry) {
            new JsonSlurper().parseText ClientBuilder.newClient().
                    target('http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select'.toURI()).
                    queryParam('q', qry).
                    queryParam('rows', 20).
                    queryParam('wt', 'json').
                    request().
                    get(String)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When run, you'll notice two files are created: "littleproxy_cert" and "littleproxy_keystore.jks". I may need to setup this certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the certificate to JRE in order to make it work. After running the script two files will occur (as in comments):
- littleproxy_cert
- littleproxy_keystore.jks

Run the following command to import the certificate:

```
keytool -import -file littleproxy_cert -alias littleproxy -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

The default password is *changeit*. You probably haven't changed it ;)

P.S. Upvoted for preparing a running example - still so rare here.

Comment: Thank you for this - it solved the problem. I had to run `keytool` with sudo on OS X and the test is working for HTTPS.